# Applying a HierarchicalDataTemplate to a Grouping

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm binding a `TreeView` to an `ILookup<Foo, Bar>`.

This means each item in the first level is an `IGrouping<Foo, Bar>`, and each item in the second level is a `Bar`.

How can I create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that will be matched to the first level?

Alternatively: How do I create a `TreeView` that uses adequate templates for `Foo` and `Bar` when bound to the lookup?

---

My workaround was to create a `FooVM` type that wraps a `Foo` and `IEnumerable<Bar>`, exposing `IEnumerable<FooVM>` instead of `ILookup<Foo, Bar>`, but I'm still interested in a WPF solution.